# Codeigniter file upload class

Tags: image, file, codeigniter

What would be a better way.

I have a form which accepts a certain width and height.

Say,

```
    $config['max_width']  = '270';
    $config['max_height']  = '280';
```

Would it be better to accept larger sized images and then just resize them to those after uploading rather than restricting them in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

CI have their own library for image re-size. So you should accept any image size. Then you can resize it with below code.

```
$config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
$config['source_image'] = '/path/to/image/img_name.jpg';
$config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
$config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
$config['width']     = 270;
$config['height']   = 280;    
$this->load->library('image_lib', $config);     
$this->image_lib->resize();
```

source: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/image_lib.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes it would be better to give your users more flexibility in file upload options.

This is a great class for resizing images https://github.com/Nimrod007/PHP_image_resize